# Google Sheets - Importrange Based on Date

Tags: filter, google-sheets, importrange

I have one spreadsheet that constantly gathers timesheets:

```
A        B            C
Id |    Date    |   Time
02   2018-05-26      60
10   2018-05-25      40
03   2018-05-23      30
12   2018-05-20      95
02   2018-05-18      15
...
```

On another spreadsheet, I have a date.

```
         A
1    2018-05-28
```

I need to import all of the timesheets that were in that week (so the 7 days before that day.)

```
Dates >= 2018-05-21
```

Therefore, I need:

```
A        B            C
Id |    Date    |   Time
02   2018-05-26      60
10   2018-05-25      40
03   2018-05-23      30
```

I have been trying to use:

```
=query(importrange("url", "A2:C"), "SELECT * WHERE Col3 >= A1")
```

Yet, this gives a `#VALUE` Error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dates as criteria have to be formatted into the query string. Format A1-7 as yyyy-mm-dd with the text function.

```
=query(url!A2:C, "SELECT A,B,C WHERE B >= date'" & text(A1-7, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "'")
'(looks like...)
=query(url!A2:C, "SELECT A,B,C WHERE B >= date'2018-05-21'")
```

No need for ImportRange.

[image]

For data in an external spreadsheet, use Filter instead of Query. In G1 in the viewable linked spreadsheet:

```
=filter(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DxQH9i-9kdQKyJZCYbR1OKOOlyVKVJ02Lr_5JRASZbM/edit", "Sheet1!A2:C"), IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DxQH9i-9kdQKyJZCYbR1OKOOlyVKVJ02Lr_5JRASZbM/edit", "Sheet1!B2:B")>=A1-7)
```

[image]

Viewable google-sheet [linked here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qv9QPLurYmJfmtVnTddTC8R6YfZCmg0t7Nt2CZTdY3s/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: I plugged that in with the url and still got a Formula Parse Error: =query("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/id#gid=0"!A2:C, "SELECT A,B,C WHERE B >= date'" & text(A2-7, "yyyy-mm-dd") & "'")

Comment: See the linked google-sheet I added to my answer. I think I thought your external worksheet was in the same workbook and caleed *url*.

Comment: see addendum added above.